# Add Gradient background to layouts in Xamarin Forms visual studio

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2015

I am a newbie in Xamarin Forms, I create a ContentPage for Menu. I need linear gradient color at its background. But I can't find any link which tell me how to create background gradient color. I also want that color place at button background like selector in android. If you have any information please give reply.

Comment: did you find any solutions or plugin?

Comment: No still searching, one way is using image. But not convenient. Other C# library not able to integrate.

Comment: Also see https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22440/gradient-as-background-color

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In below code we can set Horizontal and Vertical Gradient(I put it in #region) for any Layout in below I write for StackLayout if you want to write another Layout just replace your Layout on StackLayout.

**In PCL:**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace GradientColor
 {
   public class GradientColorStack : StackLayout
    {
      public Color StartColor { get; set; }
      public Color EndColor { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

**Xamarin.Android:**

```
  using System;
  using GradientColor;
  using GradientColor.Droid;
  using Xamarin.Forms;
  using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
  [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(GradientColorStack), typeof(GradientColorStackRenderer))]

 namespace GradientColor.Droid
  {
     public class GradientColorStackRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<StackLayout>
       {
    private Color StartColor { get; set; }
    private Color EndColor { get; set; }

    protected override void DispatchDraw(global::Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
      {
        #region for Vertical Gradient
        //var gradient = new Android.Graphics.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, Height,
        #endregion

        #region for Horizontal Gradient
     var gradient = new Android.Graphics.LinearGradient(0, 0, Width, 0,
          #endregion

            this.StartColor.ToAndroid(),
            this.EndColor.ToAndroid(),
            Android.Graphics.Shader.TileMode.Mirror);

        var paint = new Android.Graphics.Paint()
        {
            Dither = true,
        };
        paint.SetShader(gradient);
        canvas.DrawPaint(paint);
        base.DispatchDraw(canvas);
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<StackLayout> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            var stack = e.NewElement as GradientColorStack;
            this.StartColor = stack.StartColor;
            this.EndColor = stack.EndColor;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"ERROR:", ex.Message);
        }
      }
   }
}
```

**Xamarin.iOS:**

```
  using System;
  using CoreAnimation;
  using CoreGraphics;
  using GradientColor;
  using GradientColor.iOS;
  using Xamarin.Forms;
  using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
  [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(GradientColorStack), typeof(GradientColorStackRenderer))]

 namespace GradientColor.iOS
   {
public class GradientColorStackRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<StackLayout>
    {
      public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
      {
        base.Draw(rect);
        GradientColorStack stack = (GradientColorStack)this.Element;
        CGColor startColor = stack.StartColor.ToCGColor();

        CGColor endColor = stack.EndColor.ToCGColor();

        #region for Vertical Gradient

        var gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer();

        #endregion

        #region for Horizontal Gradient

        //var gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer()
        //{
        //  StartPoint = new CGPoint(0, 0.5),
        //  EndPoint = new CGPoint(1, 0.5)
        //};

        #endregion



        gradientLayer.Frame = rect;
        gradientLayer.Colors = new CGColor[] { startColor, endColor 
        };

        NativeView.Layer.InsertSublayer(gradientLayer, 0);
      }
    }
 }
```

**In XAML:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GradientColor; assembly:GradientColor" x:Class="GradientColor.GradientColorPage">
 <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" RowSpacing="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Olive">
         <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="Normal color for stacklayout" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  TextColor="White"/>
         </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
         <local:GradientColorStack StartColor="Green" EndColor="Red">
               <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
               <Label Text="Gradient color for StackLayout" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"   TextColor="White"/>
               </StackLayout>

         </local:GradientColorStack>
     </Grid>
   </Grid>
  </ContentPage>
```

Comment: How do you set dynamic color that is define in a resource dictionary? Using  StartColor="{DynamicResouce MyColor}" does not convert it to color.

Comment: Venkata Swamy Balaraju as is, it works perfectly, but is saying that the call of `VisualElementRenderer` is obsolete and I'm afraid that it might work now, but break in the future, do you know how to make the code up to date?

Comment: @Lvkz I had the same problem (and I like to treat warnings as errors, so have to resolve all obsolete warnings). I added a non-default constructor to the class, so in my case: 

`protected GradientAbsoluteLayoutRenderer(Context context) : base(context) {}`

Which resolved the warning. If I can convince my 'droid emulator to actually start I'll test it and let you know if it works correctly..

Comment: ^^ Should have been a public constructor. Worked.

Comment: @matt.chatterley You are correct!! That's how I solved it!! And it works correctly, no warnings nor errors. :)

Comment: Sorry to resurrect an old thread... First, thanks for this! It saved me a bunch of time. What may save others a bunch of time is changing the Android `DrawPaint` into a `DrawRect` call. This inexplicably misbehaves in some situations on newer Android builds as-is. Not sure if XF or Android is to blame, but that was the fix for me. HTH.

Comment: Change DrawPaint on Android to canvas.DrawRect(new Android.Graphics.Rect(0, 0, Width, Height), paint); to prevent it drawing over the entire screen.

Comment: can you help me i have implemented this method but i am facing some crash on some android device 

Canvas: trying to draw too large(125107200bytes) bitmap

this is the error i see

Answer (score 23):

For those who want a full featured gradient in Xamarin.Forms apps, there is my code:

**In your PCL**

`GradientLayout.cs`

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyProject.Renderers
{
    public class GradientLayout : StackLayout
    {
        public string ColorsList { get; set; }
      
        public Color[] Colors
        {
            get
            {
                string[] hex = ColorsList.Split(',');
                Color[] colors = new Color[hex.Length];

                for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i++)
                {
                    colors[i] = Color.FromHex(hex[i].Trim());
                }

                return colors;
            }
        }

        public GradientColorStackMode Mode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`GradientColorStackMode.cs`

```
namespace MyProject.Renderers
{
    public enum GradientColorStackMode
    {
        ToRight,
        ToLeft,
        ToTop,
        ToBottom,
        ToTopLeft,
        ToTopRight,
        ToBottomLeft,
        ToBottomRight
    }
}
```

**In your iOS project**

`GradientLayoutRenderer.cs`

```
using CoreAnimation;
using CoreGraphics;
using MyProject.Renderers;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(GradientLayout), typeof(GradientLayoutRenderer))]

namespace MyProject.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class GradientLayoutRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<StackLayout>
    {
        public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
        {
            base.Draw(rect);
            GradientLayout layout = (GradientLayout)Element;

            CGColor[] colors = new CGColor[layout.Colors.Length];

            for (int i = 0, l = colors.Length; i < l; i++)
            {
                colors[i] = layout.Colors[i].ToCGColor();
            }

            var gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer();

            switch (layout.Mode)
            {
                default:
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToRight:
                    gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(0, 0.5);
                    gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(1, 0.5);
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToLeft:
                    gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(1, 0.5);
                    gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(0, 0.5);
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToTop:
                    gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(0.5, 1);
                    gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(0.5, 0);
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToBottom:
                    gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(0.5, 0);
                    gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(0.5, 1);
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToTopLeft:
                    gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(1, 1);
                    gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(0, 0);
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToTopRight:
                    gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(0, 1);
                    gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(1, 0);
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToBottomLeft:
                    gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(1, 0);
                    gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(0, 1);
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToBottomRight:
                    gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(0, 0);
                    gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(1, 1);
                    break;
            }

            gradientLayer.Frame = rect;
            gradientLayer.Colors = colors;

            NativeView.Layer.InsertSublayer(gradientLayer, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

**In your Android Project**

`GradientLayoutRenderer.cs`

```
using System;
using Android.Content;
using MyProject.Renderers;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(GradientLayout), typeof(GradientLayoutRenderer))]

namespace MyProject.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class GradientLayoutRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<StackLayout>
    {
        private Color[] Colors { get; set; }

        private GradientColorStackMode Mode { get; set; }

        public GradientLayoutRenderer(Context ctx) : base(ctx)
        { }

        protected override void DispatchDraw(global::Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
        {
            Android.Graphics.LinearGradient gradient;

            int[] colors = new int[Colors.Length];

            for (int i = 0, l = Colors.Length; i < l; i++)
            {
                colors[i] = Colors[i].ToAndroid().ToArgb();
            }

            switch (Mode)
            {
                default:
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToRight:
                    gradient = new Android.Graphics.LinearGradient(0, 0, Width, 0, colors, null, Android.Graphics.Shader.TileMode.Mirror);
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToLeft:
                    gradient = new Android.Graphics.LinearGradient(Width, 0, 0, 0, colors, null, Android.Graphics.Shader.TileMode.Mirror);
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToTop:
                    gradient = new Android.Graphics.LinearGradient(0, Height, 0, 0, colors, null, Android.Graphics.Shader.TileMode.Mirror);
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToBottom:
                   gradient = new Android.Graphics.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, Height, colors, null, Android.Graphics.Shader.TileMode.Mirror);
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToTopLeft:
                    gradient = new Android.Graphics.LinearGradient(Width, Height, 0, 0, colors, null, Android.Graphics.Shader.TileMode.Mirror);
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToTopRight:
                    gradient = new Android.Graphics.LinearGradient(0, Height, Width, 0, colors, null, Android.Graphics.Shader.TileMode.Mirror);
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToBottomLeft:
                    gradient = new Android.Graphics.LinearGradient(Width, 0, 0, Height, colors, null, Android.Graphics.Shader.TileMode.Mirror);
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToBottomRight:
                    gradient = new Android.Graphics.LinearGradient(0, 0, Width, Height, colors, null, Android.Graphics.Shader.TileMode.Mirror);
                    break;
            }

            var paint = new Android.Graphics.Paint()
            {
                Dither = true,
            };

            paint.SetShader(gradient);
            canvas.DrawPaint(paint);

            base.DispatchDraw(canvas);
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<StackLayout> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
                return;

            try
            {
                if (e.NewElement is GradientLayout layout)
                {
                    Colors = layout.Colors;
                    Mode = layout.Mode;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"ERROR:", ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**In UWP project**

`GradientLayoutRenderer.cs`

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using MyProject.Renderers;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP;
using Point = Windows.Foundation.Point;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(GradientLayout), typeof(GradientLayoutRenderer))]

namespace MyProject.UWP.Renderers
{
    public class GradientLayoutRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<StackLayout, Panel>
    {
        private Color[] Colors { get; set; }

        private GradientColorStackMode Mode { get; set; }

        protected override void UpdateBackgroundColor()
        {
            base.UpdateBackgroundColor();

            LinearGradientBrush gradient;

            GradientStopCollection stopCollection = new GradientStopCollection();

            for (int i = 0, l = Colors.Length; i < l; i++)
            {
                stopCollection.Add(new GradientStop
                {
                    Color = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb((byte)(Colors[i].A * byte.MaxValue), (byte)(Colors[i].R * byte.MaxValue), (byte)(Colors[i].G * byte.MaxValue), (byte)(Colors[i].B * byte.MaxValue)),
                    Offset = (double)i / Colors.Length
                });
            }

            switch (Mode)
            {
                default:
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToRight:
                    gradient = new LinearGradientBrush
                    {
                        GradientStops = stopCollection,
                        StartPoint = new Point(0, 0.5),
                        EndPoint = new Point(1, 0.5)
                    };
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToLeft:
                    gradient = new LinearGradientBrush
                    {
                        GradientStops = stopCollection,
                        StartPoint = new Point(1, 0.5),
                        EndPoint = new Point(0, 0.5)
                    };
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToTop:
                    gradient = new LinearGradientBrush
                    {
                        GradientStops = stopCollection,
                        StartPoint = new Point(0.5, 1),
                        EndPoint = new Point(0.5, 0)
                    };
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToBottom:
                    gradient = new LinearGradientBrush
                    {
                        GradientStops = stopCollection,
                        StartPoint = new Point(0.5, 0),
                        EndPoint = new Point(0.5, 1)
                    };
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToTopLeft:
                    gradient = new LinearGradientBrush
                    {
                        GradientStops = stopCollection,
                        StartPoint = new Point(1, 1),
                        EndPoint = new Point(0, 0)
                    };
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToTopRight:
                    gradient = new LinearGradientBrush
                    {
                        GradientStops = stopCollection,
                        StartPoint = new Point(0, 1),
                        EndPoint = new Point(1, 0)
                    };
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToBottomLeft:
                    gradient = new LinearGradientBrush
                    {
                        GradientStops = stopCollection,
                        StartPoint = new Point(1, 0),
                        EndPoint = new Point(0, 1)
                    };
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToBottomRight:
                    gradient = new LinearGradientBrush
                    {
                        GradientStops = stopCollection,
                        StartPoint = new Point(0, 0),
                        EndPoint = new Point(1, 1)
                    };
                    break;
            }

            Background = gradient;
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<StackLayout> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
                return;

            try
            {
                if (e.NewElement is GradientLayout stack)
                {
                    Colors = stack.Colors;
                    Mode = stack.Mode;

                    UpdateBackgroundColor();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"ERROR:", ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**In your XAML pages**

```
<renderers:GradientLayout
    ColorsList="#dd8f68,#a9a9a9,#3a3939"
    Mode="ToBottomRight">

    <!-- Your content -->

</renderers:GradientLayout>
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you this implementation saved my bacon. One of the only posts I could find that handled Android, IOs and UWP

Comment: Can someone help me with this implementation. In the PCL the Colors array is never create/initialized.  Since it is null I'm getting an exception.  I'm just curious how/where I define the Colors in the array.  In the xaml the ColorsList is defined, but that's all I can see.  :P

Comment: @Valerie have you defined the ColorsList attribute of GradientLayout in your xaml document? Since the Colors array is only a getter, you are not able to directly edit this array since it is automatically generated with the value in ColorsList

Comment: @na2axl thanks for the support.  Yes, I copied the example xaml, which has the ColorsList parameter.  Maybe it's a timing issue with the ui loading as I'm using Freshmvvm.

Comment: @Valerie sorry but I don't know the behaviour of Freshmvvm, so I'm not able to say that is the source of the problem. But you can try to use a default value for ColorsList in GradientLayout class so if it is a binding problem the default value will be used instead....

Comment: Answer of the month, maybe year. Very thorough and inclusive of all platforms. Thank you.

Comment: @na2axl Thank you! It appears there is an error in the Android Renderer. Line 

`if (e.NewElement is GradientLayoutRenderer layout)`

Should read

`if (e.NewElement is GradientLayout layout)`

Comment: Oh it's true, sorry for the mistake :-)

Answer (score 16):

Add the SkiaSharp Nuget to your project togehter with this class. Use it in your xaml whereever you need a gradient.

```
public partial class GradientView : ContentView
{
    public Color StartColor { get; set; } = Color.Transparent;
    public Color EndColor { get; set; } = Color.Transparent;
    public bool Horizontal { get; set; } = false;

    public GradientView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SKCanvasView canvasView = new SKCanvasView();
        canvasView.PaintSurface += OnCanvasViewPaintSurface;
        Content = canvasView;
    }

    void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    {
        SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
        SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
        SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

        canvas.Clear();

        var colors = new SKColor[] { StartColor.ToSKColor(), EndColor.ToSKColor()};
        SKPoint startPoint = new SKPoint(0,0);
        SKPoint endPoint = Horizontal ? new SKPoint(info.Width, 0) : new SKPoint(0, info.Height);

        var shader = SKShader.CreateLinearGradient(startPoint, endPoint, colors, null, SKShaderTileMode.Clamp);

        SKPaint paint = new SKPaint
        {
            Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill,
            Shader = shader
        };

        canvas.DrawRect(new SKRect(0, 0, info.Width, info.Height), paint);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post how the xaml will look like?

Comment: Add your local namespace to the xaml and then use the GradientView like this: <local:GradientView StartColor="Red" EndColor="Green" />

Comment: This is not a background image, it's simply a canvas in the view... so when you scroll the image scrolls to. The good solution would be to set the canvas as the content page background image.

Comment: The solution above worked like a charm. Was able to set this as a Grid Background and have a simple gradient

Comment: @Kedu This code snippet generates a frame around the gradient. How do I remove the frame?

Comment: NOTE: mattleibow (who contributes to SkiaSharp dev) mentions *"a bitmap the size of the screen is allocated."* [when drawing gradient on whole screen], so be aware of that memory cost, plus the added app size for the library. A ways down in this thread: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22440/gradient-as-background-color

Answer (score 5):

For now there is no real drawing functionality to do that. You may want to set an image as background, you can provide many pictures for the different folders (hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, etc...)
Or you can use [custom renderers](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/) to extend ContentPage class into your own.

You can take a look at this discussion at Xamarin Forums.
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22440/gradient-as-background-color

Answer (score 5):

First comment ever on SO.

using [na2xl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9654227/na2axl) answer as an Effect

Effects can be attached to different component, are fully reusable, and don't force you to subclass Forms components.

I added a location system to tune where each color starts and ends in the gradient - 0 absolute beginning / 1 absolute end.

**in the NetStandard lib**

```
using System.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace YourProject.Effects
{
    public class GradientEffect : RoutingEffect
    {
        public GradientEffect() : base("YourCompany.GradientEffect")
        {
        }

        public string Colors { get; set; }

        public GradientMode Mode { get; set; }

        public Color[] ColorList => Colors.Split(',').Select(i => Color.FromHex(i.Trim())).ToArray();

        public string Locations { get; set; }

        public float[] LocationList => Locations.Split(',').Select(float.Parse).ToArray();

    }

    public enum GradientMode
    {
        ToRight,
        ToLeft,
        ToTop,
        ToBottom,
        ToTopLeft,
        ToTopRight,
        ToBottomLeft,
        ToBottomRight,
        Null
    }
}
```

**in the iOS project**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using CoreAnimation;
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using YourProject.Effects;
using YourProject.iOS.Effects;
using Serilog;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;


[assembly:ResolutionGroupName ("YourCompany")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(IosGradientEffect), "GradientEffect")]
namespace YourProject.iOS.Effects
{
    public class IosGradientEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            try
            {
                var nativeView = Control ?? Container;
                var effect = (GradientEffect) Element.Effects.FirstOrDefault(e => e is GradientEffect);
                if (effect == null) return;

                var colors = effect.ColorList.Select(i => i.ToCGColor()).ToArray();

                var gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer
                {
                    Locations = effect.LocationList?.Select(i => new NSNumber(i)).ToArray()
                };

                switch (effect.Mode)
                {
                    default:
                        gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(0, 0.5);
                        gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(1, 0.5);
                        break;
                    case GradientMode.ToLeft:
                        gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(1, 0.5);
                        gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(0, 0.5);
                        break;
                    case GradientMode.ToTop:
                        gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(0.5, 1);
                        gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(0.5, 0);
                        break;
                    case GradientMode.ToBottom:
                        gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(0.5, 0);
                        gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(0.5, 1);
                        break;
                    case GradientMode.ToTopLeft:
                        gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(1, 1);
                        gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(0, 0);
                        break;
                    case GradientMode.ToTopRight:
                        gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(0, 1);
                        gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(1, 0);
                        break;
                    case GradientMode.ToBottomLeft:
                        gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(1, 0);
                        gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(0, 1);
                        break;
                    case GradientMode.ToBottomRight:
                        gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(0, 0);
                        gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(1, 1);
                        break;
                }

                gradientLayer.Frame = nativeView.Bounds;
                gradientLayer.Colors = colors;

                nativeView.Layer.InsertSublayer(gradientLayer, 0);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            Log.Debug("Gradient Effect Detached");
        }
    }
}
```

** in the Android project**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables.Shapes;
using YourProject.Droid.Effects;
using YourProject.Effects;
using Serilog;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly:ResolutionGroupName ("YourCompany")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(AndroidGradientEffect), "GradientEffect")]
namespace YourProject.Droid.Effects
{
    public class AndroidGradientEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            try
            {
                var effect = (GradientEffect) Element.Effects.FirstOrDefault(e => e is GradientEffect);

                var nativeView = Control ?? Container;

                var colors = effect.ColorList.Select(i => i.ToAndroid().ToArgb()).ToArray();

                var paint = new PaintDrawable();
                paint.Shape = new RectShape();
                paint.SetShaderFactory(new GradientShaderFactory(colors, effect.LocationList, Shader.TileMode.Mirror, effect.Mode));

                nativeView.SetBackgroundDrawable(paint);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal("Couldn't set property for view with effect ex:" + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            Log.Debug("Android Gradient Effect detached");
        }
    }

    internal class GradientShaderFactory : ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory
    {
        private readonly Shader.TileMode _tileMode;
        private readonly int[] _colors;
        private readonly float[] _locations;
        private readonly GradientMode _gradientMode;


        internal GradientShaderFactory(int[] colors, float[] locations, Shader.TileMode tileMode,
            GradientMode gradientMode)
        {
            _colors = colors;
            _locations = locations;
            _tileMode = tileMode;
            _gradientMode = gradientMode;
        }

        public override Shader Resize(int width, int height)
        {
            LinearGradient gradient;
            switch (_gradientMode)
                {
                    default:
                        gradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, width, 0, _colors, _locations,
                            _tileMode);
                        break;
                    case GradientMode.ToLeft:
                        gradient = new LinearGradient(width, 0, 0, 0, _colors, _locations,
                            _tileMode);
                        break;
                    case GradientMode.ToTop:
                        gradient = new LinearGradient(0, height, 0, 0, _colors, _locations,
                            _tileMode);
                        break;
                    case GradientMode.ToBottom:
                        gradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height, _colors, _locations,
                            _tileMode);
                        break;
                    case GradientMode.ToTopLeft:
                        gradient = new LinearGradient(width, height, 0, 0,
                            _colors, _locations,
                            _tileMode);
                        break;
                    case GradientMode.ToTopRight:
                        gradient = new LinearGradient(0, height, width,0 ,
                            _colors, _locations,
                            _tileMode);
                        break;
                    case GradientMode.ToBottomLeft:
                        gradient = new LinearGradient(width, 0, 0, height,
                            _colors, _locations,
                            _tileMode);
                        break;
                    case GradientMode.ToBottomRight:
                        gradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, width, height,
                            _colors,_locations,
                            _tileMode);
                        break;
                }

            return gradient;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a usage example for this ?  I can't quite understand what the parameters should be set to.

Comment: Sure
`<effects:GradientEffect
        Colors="#071c33,#071c33,#030c17"
        Mode="ToBottomRight"
        Locations="0,.175,1" />`

Answer (score 2):

The [XFGloss](http://tommyb.com/open-source-projects/xfgloss/) project adds the ability to add gradients via XAML.

For example:

```
    <xfg:ContentPageGloss.BackgroundGradient>
        <xfg:Gradient Rotation="150">
            <xfg:GradientStep StepColor="White" StepPercentage="0" />
            <xfg:GradientStep StepColor="White" StepPercentage=".5" />
            <xfg:GradientStep StepColor="#ccd9ff" StepPercentage="1" />
        </xfg:Gradient>
    </xfg:ContentPageGloss.BackgroundGradient>
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a ContentView of mine that I wrote.  You can use as-is in your PCL/Core project without a CustomRender. It has a dependancy on SkiaSharp though.

It has an ItemTemplate and Bindable properties.

[Xamarin Forms Gradient Content View](https://gist.github.com/rogerwcpt/699d119ac3927cad10cda5254de63acc)

Answer (score 0):

The Android draw mehtod was not working for me so, so I extended it a bit:

```
    protected override void DispatchDraw(global::Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
    {
        Android.Graphics.LinearGradient gradient;

        using (var path = new Android.Graphics.Path())
        using(var paint = new Android.Graphics.Paint()
            {
                Dither = true,
                AntiAlias = true,
            })
        using (Android.Graphics.Path.Direction direction = Android.Graphics.Path.Direction.Cw)
        using (var rect = new Android.Graphics.RectF(0, 0, (float)canvas.Width, (float)canvas.Height))
        {
            if (Element.Orientation == StackOrientation.Vertical)
                gradient = new Android.Graphics.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, Height, this.StartColor.ToAndroid(),
                   this.EndColor.ToAndroid(),
                   Android.Graphics.Shader.TileMode.Mirror);
            else
                gradient = new Android.Graphics.LinearGradient(0, 0, Width, 0, this.StartColor.ToAndroid(),
                   this.EndColor.ToAndroid(),
                   Android.Graphics.Shader.TileMode.Mirror);

            path.AddRect(rect, direction);
            paint.SetShader(gradient);
            canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
        }
        base.DispatchDraw(canvas);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the I Edited the class given by @na2axl to use it to give rbga colors with this format "R,G,B,A:R,G,B,A". All colors will be separated by colon and their values will be separated by qoma (,) like "255,255,255,100:255,255,255,0"

```
public class GradientLayout : StackLayout
{
    public string ColorsList { get; set; }

    public Color[] Colors
    {
        get
        {
            string[] rgbacolor = ColorsList.Split(':');
            Color[] colors = new Color[rgbacolor.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < rgbacolor.Length; i++) {
                string[] colorcodes = rgbacolor[i].Trim().Split(',');
                double r = double.Parse(colorcodes[0].Trim());
                double g = double.Parse(colorcodes[1].Trim());
                double b = double.Parse(colorcodes[2].Trim());
                double a = double.Parse(colorcodes[3].Trim());
                colors[i] = Color.FromRgba(r,g,b,a);
                //Color.FromHex(rgbacolor[i].Trim());
            }
            return colors;
        }
    }

    public GradientColorStackMode Mode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I am using this code in my app

<renderers:GradientLayout HeightRequest="100" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  VerticalOptions="End" ColorsList="255,255,255,100:255,255,255,0" Mode="ToTop" />

I am unable to use HeightRequest... Its always showing whole screen rather just 100 pixels

Comment: see this image https://www.dropbox.com/s/9a5azc0xf0op114/Screenshot.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is the one described here at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/magic-gradients-xamarinforms/

Install the nuget MagicGradients

In app.xaml add the line

```
<Application.Resources>
<!-- ..... -->
<Style TargetType="ContentPage" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
<Setter Property="ControlTemplate">
<Setter.Value>
<ControlTemplate>
<Grid> 
<magicGradients:GradientView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
<magicGradients:GradientView.GradientSource>
<magicGradients:LinearGradient Angle="320">
<magicGradients:GradientStop Color="#338af9" Offset="0" />
<magicGradients:GradientStop Color="#2ff8ff" Offset="1" />
</magicGradients:LinearGradient>
</magicGradients:GradientView.GradientSource>
</magicGradients:GradientView>
<ContentPresenter />
</Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
<!-- ..... --->
</Application.Resources>
```

The above will apply Linear gradient to your ContentPage

Answer (score 0):

Starting Xamarin Forms 4.8 you can add the built-in gradient.

```
<Frame BorderColor="LightGray"
   HasShadow="True"
   CornerRadius="12"
   HeightRequest="120"
   WidthRequest="120">
<Frame.Background>
    <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.5,0.5"
                         Radius="0.5">
        <GradientStop Color="Red"
                      Offset="0.1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="DarkBlue"
                      Offset="1.0"/>
    </RadialGradientBrush>
</Frame.Background>
```

Source and details on Microsoft DevBlogs: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarinforms-4-8-gradients-brushes/

Answer (score -2):

To use dynamic Resources, you will have to make your properties bindable, like this

```
    public static BindableProperty StartColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CustomContentPage), typeof(Color), typeof(CustomButton), default(Color), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay);

    public Color StartColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(StartColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PaddingProperty, value); }
    }


    public static BindableProperty EndColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CustomContentPage), typeof(Color), typeof(CustomButton), default(Color), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay);

    public Color EndColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(EndColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PaddingProperty, value); }
    }
```