# Gradient stacklayout for xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin forms now. I have a requirement to have a gradient stacklayout view with some width set to the stack layout which is greater than the device's portrait width. Setting this width will ensure that the stacklayout will be fit in portrait view and in landscape the stacklayout with the width can be seen. Here I need a top to bottom gradient stacklayout. I have seen some of the posts with custom renderers for stacklayout and that works good.

But when i used those renderers, i could see that on changing the orientation from portrait to landscape in live scenario, the drawn gradient layout width is seen as the portrait width with the remaining area as empty. See the attached images for

**portrait**

[![portrait][1]][1]

***and landscape***

[image: landscape]

Here is the XAML code image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eP9A.png)

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
<Image Source="img_bg.png" Aspect="AspectFill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"/>
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Spacing="0" Padding="0,20,0,0">
  <Image Source="img_logo.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="80"/>
  <ScrollView>
          <local:GradientStack StartColor="#99ddde" EndColor="#2896b1" HeightRequest="375" WidthRequest="300" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="25,5,25,0" Margin="20,25,20,0" Spacing="0">
      <Label Text="Log in" HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="#e5f8fc" FontSize="34"/>
      <Label Text="Username" HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="#e5f8fc" FontSize="20" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
      <local:CustomBorderEntry x:Name="txtUserName" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                               HeightRequest="38" Margin="0,5,0,0"
                               BackgroundColor="#e5f8fc" FontSize="16"
                               TextColor ="#201f1f"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" />
      <Label Text="Password" HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="#e5f8fc" FontSize="20" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
      <local:CustomBorderEntry x:Name="txtPassword" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                               HeightRequest="38" Margin="0,5,0,0"
                               BackgroundColor="#e5f8fc" FontSize="16"
                               TextColor ="#201f1f"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" IsPassword="true"/>
      <Label Text="Event Code" HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="#e5f8fc" FontSize="20" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
      <local:CustomBorderEntry x:Name="txtEventCode" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                               HeightRequest="36" Margin="0,5,0,0"
                               BackgroundColor="#e5f8fc" FontSize="16"
                               TextColor ="#201f1f"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"/>
      <StackLayout Margin="0,20,0,0" Padding="0,1,0,0" BackgroundColor="#e5f8fc" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="45">
        <local:GradientStack StartColor="#2c7f9d" EndColor="#0e5a8c" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="slLogin">
          <Label Text="Log in" FontSize="20" TextColor="#e5f8fc" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        </local:GradientStack>            
      </StackLayout>
    </local:GradientStack>
  </ScrollView>
</StackLayout>
```

custom control:

```
public class GradientStack : StackLayout
{
    public Color StartColor { get; set; }
    public Color EndColor { get; set; }
}
```

custom Renderer:

```
public class GradientStackRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<GradientStack>
{
    public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
    {
        base.Draw(rect);
        CAGradientLayer layer = new CAGradientLayer();
        layer.Frame = rect;
        layer.Colors = new CGColor[] {
            Element.StartColor.ToCGColor(),
            Element.EndColor.ToCGColor()
        };
        Layer.InsertSublayer(layer, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? I think you could use `HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"` with a `Margin` for this.

Comment: @DennisSchröer - Hi Dennis, If i am using a normal stacklayout, it works fine. Here I am using a custom renderer for making it gradient stacklayout.   I got the layout from below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848545/add-gradient-background-to-layouts-in-xamarin-forms-visual-studio

Comment: can you show your xaml?

Comment: @YuriS I have attched the XAML code image

Comment: can you edit the question and paste the code? if I want to reproduce I need to do a lot of typing

Comment: @YuriS Code is added

Comment: Can you post your custom renderer too. I understood that it is causing problem and it works without custom renderer, correct? Also, definition of your GradientStack. And CustomBorderEntry

Comment: including StartColor/EndColor bindible properties

Comment: @YuriS - Leave the border entry, u can use entry control instead. The custom control and custom iOS renderer codes are added.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that on simulator 6 os 10.3 and iPad 10.3. Besides recommendation to make Start/Stop colors bindable attributes cannot help you more. It works for me

Comment: @YuriS can u pls share ur code so that i can check it here and verify.

Comment: I didn't keep sources for 10 days, sorry. But if you share yours I can check them

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem with WidthRequest=400. I don't think you should explicitly set width or height requests if you are using FillAndExpand. besides mixing AbsoluteLayout with constraints and stack layouts inside probably not the best design. I found one more thing. The function Draw in renderer is not called when device changes orientation so rectangle is never redrawn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution. When size of the stack layout changed we need to force redraw.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(GradientStack), typeof(GradientStackRenderer))]

namespace yournamespace.iOS
{
    class GradientStackRenderer : ViewRenderer<StackLayout, UIView>
    {

        public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
        {
            base.Draw(rect);
            CAGradientLayer layer = new CAGradientLayer();
            layer.Frame = rect;
            layer.Colors = new CGColor[]
            {
                ((GradientStack)Element).StartColor.ToCGColor(),
                ((GradientStack)Element).EndColor.ToCGColor()
            };

            if(Layer.Sublayers[0] is CAGradientLayer)
                Layer.ReplaceSublayer(Layer.Sublayers[0], layer);
            else
                Layer.InsertSublayer(layer, 0);

        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if(e.PropertyName=="Width")
                SetNeedsDisplay();
        }


    }
}
```

We also don't want to add a layer every time we draw, so we check and replace our layer if already in sublayers.

I also would remove unnecessary size requests

```
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <Image Source="img_bg.png" Aspect="AspectFill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"/>
        <StackLayout  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Spacing="0" Padding="0,20,0,0">
            <Image Source="img_bg.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="80"/>
            <ScrollView>
                <local:GradientStack StartColor="#99ddde" EndColor="#2896b1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="25,5,25,20" Margin="20,25,20,0" Spacing="0">
                    <Label Text="Log in" HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="#e5f8fc" FontSize="34"/>
                    <Label Text="Username" HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="#e5f8fc" FontSize="20" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                    <local:CustomBorderEntry x:Name="txtUserName" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                           HeightRequest="38" Margin="0,5,0,0"
                           BackgroundColor="#e5f8fc" FontSize="16"
                           TextColor ="#201f1f"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" />
                    <Label Text="Password" HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="#e5f8fc" FontSize="20" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                    <local:CustomBorderEntry x:Name="txtPassword" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                           HeightRequest="38" Margin="0,5,0,0"
                           BackgroundColor="#e5f8fc" FontSize="16"
                           TextColor ="#201f1f"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" IsPassword="true"/>
                    <Label Text="Event Code" HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="#e5f8fc" FontSize="20" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                    <local:CustomBorderEntry x:Name="txtEventCode" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                           HeightRequest="36" Margin="0,5,0,0"
                           BackgroundColor="#e5f8fc" FontSize="16"
                           TextColor ="#201f1f"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"/>
                    <StackLayout Margin="0,20,0,0" Padding="0,1,0,0" BackgroundColor="#e5f8fc" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="45">
                        <local:GradientStack StartColor="#2c7f9d" EndColor="#0e5a8c" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="slLogin">
                            <Label Text="Log in" FontSize="20" TextColor="#e5f8fc" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                        </local:GradientStack>
                    </StackLayout>
                </local:GradientStack>
            </ScrollView>
        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: any feedback? did you try this?

Comment: I have posted a different question. Can u pls check that too   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45216192/reinitializing-masterpage-is-throwing-null-exception-in-ios-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0):

To avoid a null exception in the solution above when the redraw happens, you need to make sure that you check the Sublayers property for null like below:

```
if (Layer.Sublayers?[0] is CAGradientLayer)
{
    Layer.ReplaceSublayer(Layer.Sublayers[0], gradientLayer);
}
else
{
    Layer.InsertSublayer(gradientLayer, 0);
}
```