# Reinitializing MasterPage is throwing null exception in IOS - Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin

I have a MDPage which is a MasterDetailPage which calls side menu items list page as Master. The Detail for this is added with a new NavigationPage of a home page.

My code is

```
public MDPage(){
Master = new SideMenuPage();
InitializeComponent();
masterPage.ListView.ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;

Detail = new NavigationPage(new HomePage())
{
    BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black,
    BarTextColor = Color.White,
};}
```

I have a requirement where the NavigationPage contains a bottom menu such that on clicking a bottom menu, the MDPage needs to be reinitialized to set a new NavigationPage of a different page (say AboutUs page). So i added a parameterized constructor for MDPage and on clicking the bottom menu item i am calling `App.Current.MainPage = new MDPage("AboutUs")`.Below is the parameterized constructor.

```
  public MDPage(string bottomMenuItem)
 {
Master = new SideMenuPage();
InitializeComponent();
masterPage.ListView.ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;

if("AboutUs" == bottomMenuItem)
{
   Detail = new NavigationPage(new AboutUs())
   {
      BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black,
      BarTextColor = Color.White,
   };
}}
```

Here the MDPage constructor is called initially when i open the app. Then from the side menu i have the option to open a HomePage which is added as Detail. Note that this HomePage contains a bottom sub menu, which is nothing but an image. On tapping this, it should again reinitialize the MDPage. Here this is working fine in Andorid. But in iOS, it is throwing null exception. It is not allowing me to set `Master = new SideMenuPage();` I have found the root cause by trial and error as this code will not throw exception and it is throwing in the iOS Main.cs file. Please help me.

MainPage - XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ClubApp.Views;assembly=ClubApp"
             x:Class="ClubApp.Views.MainPage">

  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <local:MasterPage x:Name="masterPage" />
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>
  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
      <x:Arguments>

      </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System.Linq;using System.Text;using System.Threading.Tasks;using Xamarin.Forms;namespace Test.Views{
public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {

        Master = new MasterPage();
        InitializeComponent();
        masterPage.ListView.ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;

        Detail = new NavigationPage(new Views.HomePage())
        {
            BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black,
            BarTextColor = Color.White,
        };
    }

    public MainPage(string bottomMenu)
    {

        Master = new MasterPage();
        InitializeComponent();
        masterPage.ListView.ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;

        if ("News" == bottomMenu)
        {
            Detail = new NavigationPage(new Views.HomePage())
            {
                BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black,
                BarTextColor = Color.White,
            };
        }
        else if ("Profile" == bottomMenu)
        {

            Detail = new NavigationPage(new Views.Profile())
            {
                BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black,
                BarTextColor = Color.White,
            };
        }
    }

    async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var item = e.SelectedItem as MasterPageItem;
            if (item != null)
            {
                if (item.Title == "News")
                {
                    Detail = new NavigationPage(new Views.NewsPage())
                    {
                        BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black,
                        BarTextColor = Color.White,
                    };
                }

                if (item.Title == "Home")
                {

                    Detail = new NavigationPage(new Views.HomePage())
                    {
                        BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black,
                        BarTextColor = Color.White,
                    };
                }
                if (item.Title == "Profile")
                {

                    Detail = new NavigationPage(new Views.Profile())
                    {
                        BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black,
                        BarTextColor = Color.White,
                    };
                }

                masterPage.ListView.SelectedItem = null;
                IsPresented = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
}}
```

MasterPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"             x:Class="Test.Views.MasterPage">  <ContentPage.Content>
<StackLayout   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#10000c" Padding = "0,50,0,0" >
  <StackLayout  x:Name="slUserProfile" Orientation="Vertical" Spacing = "0" 
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Image Source="{Binding member_image}" x:Name="imgSideImage"
             HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill" HeightRequest="100" 
             WidthRequest="100" />

    <Label Text="{Binding name}" TextColor="#efa747" 
                          FontSize ="17"
                          HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
  </StackLayout >

  <ListView x:Name="lvSideMenu" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" SeparatorVisibility="None" 
            BackgroundColor="Black">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <StackLayout Padding="15,5,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}"/>
            <StackLayout Padding = "10,0,0,0">
              <local:CustomLabel Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   TextColor="#dac6ac" FontSize ="14"/>
            </StackLayout>
          </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</StackLayout></ContentPage.Content></ContentPage>
```

MasterPage.xaml.cs

```
using Xamarin.Forms;namespace Test.Views{
public partial class MasterPage : ContentPage
{
    public ListView ListView { get { return lvSideMenu; } }
    public Page Detail { get; set; }
    public MasterPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var masterPageItems = new List<MasterPageItem>();  
        //Fills side menu items.
        masterPageItems.Add(new MasterPageItem
        {
            Title = "Profile",
            IconSource = "profile_sidemenu.png"
        });
        masterPageItems.Add(new MasterPageItem
        {
            Title = "Home",
            IconSource = "home_smenu.png"
        });
        masterPageItems.Add(new MasterPageItem
        {
            Title = "News",
            IconSource = "news_smenu.png"
        });
        lvSideMenu.ItemsSource = masterPageItems;
        Icon = "menu.png";
        Title = "Menu";   
    }
}
public class MenuItems
{
    public string MenuTitle { get; set; }
}
public class MasterPageItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string IconSource { get; set; }
}}
```

HomePage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"           x:Class="Test.Views.HomePage" Title="Home"><ContentPage.Content><StackLayout>   <Label Text="This is Home page"/></StackLayout></ContentPage.Content></ContentPage>
```

Profile.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Test.Views.Profile" Title="Profile"><ContentPage.Content>   <StackLayout>
    <StackLayout>
      <Label Text="This is Profile page" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout HeightRequest="80">
      <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackLayout x:Name="tProfile" BackgroundColor="Red" Grid.Column="0" Spacing="0" Padding="0,10,0,10">
          <Image Source="bprofileSel.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="End"/>
          <Label Text="Profile" FontSize="10" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout x:Name="tNews" BackgroundColor="Black" Grid.Column="1" Spacing="0" Padding="0,10,0,10">
          <Image Source="bNewsUnsel.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="End"/>
          <local:CustomLabel Text="News" FontSize="10" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
 </StackLayout></ContentPage.Content></ContentPage>
```

Profile.xaml.cs

```
Using System;using System.Collections.Generic;using System.Linq;using System.Text;using System.Threading.Tasks;using Xamarin.Forms;namespace Test.Views{
public partial class Profile : ContentPage
{

    public Profile()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        try
        {
            tProfile.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
            {
                Command = new Command(() => ProfileClicked()),
            });

            tNews.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
            {
                Command = new Command(() => NewsClicked()),
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    private void ProfileClicked()
    {
        App.Current.MainPage = new MainPage("Profile");
    }

    private void NewsClicked()
    {
        App.Current.MainPage = new MainPage("News");
    }
}}
```

News page can be set similar to the profile page. In app.cs call MainPage = new MainPage()

Here when the app is launched, it will show the HomePage with the side menu. Now when i click a menu (say profile from side menu), it will take me to the profile page and according to the design a bottom submenus can be seen there. Clicking on it will cause the null exception occurring in iOS code. This is working fine in android. My assumption is the root cause is due to MasterPage reinitialization to Master. But i need this requirement to be flown like this. Please help me.

This is the error in iOS Main.cs
[image: iOS Error]

Comment: can you share the sample project?

Comment: can you try to move Master = new SideMenuPage(); below InitializeComponent()

Comment: @YuriS I will try this. I have posted the codes. Please take a look. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @YuriS Moving  Master = new SideMenuPage() did not work. Issue still occurred. I have attached the error image.

Comment: Any chance to share the complete sample project, so I don't have to recreate all that? I can probably provide the answer much faster then

Comment: I don't see SideMenuPage anywhere in your code

Comment: recreated your project here https://www.dropbox.com/s/rox6mw0hptjfxpc/ForHashimks.zip?dl=0 I cannot see the problem. It works on my simulator iOS10.3. Let me know if you have a problem with my project. If yes then you have some VS problems. If not then you have a problem with your project/code. I might be able to solve it looking in your computer.Let me know when I can remove zip file from my dropbox. I will keep it for couple days,

Comment: I will check it. Please keep it on your drop box till wednesday.

Comment: Meanwhile, can you please check this post as well? It will be really helpful.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239041/resetting-the-xconstraint-and-yconstraint-of-an-image-present-inside-a-relative

Comment: @YuriS I have checked this. And it is working fine with your app. But it is not working in my App. I am not sure why it is so. I will share you my project.    https://www.dropbox.com/s/wjiyr1bw4xgabtt/ClubApp.zip?dl=0

Comment: In constructor public MainPage(string bottomMenu) you don't have "if" for Contact and Facilities pages, so when you assign MainPage your Detail page is null.

Comment: Let me know if that helped

Comment: I have checked that, that part i did not implement (ie for contact and facilities). However i found out the actual issue and was with respect to one CustomRenderer for multiline label. Somehow the renderer is getting the control as null which caused the issue. Thanks for your help and support for helping me identify.

Comment: The project you sent me didn't have any custom renderers. Good luck with the rest

Comment: Yes I noticed that. And i checked without renderers and it worked. Later I put try catch in all the constructors and functions and put break points in all the exceptions to figure out the issue with renderer which helped me. Once again thanks a lot for your help.