# Resetting the XConstraint and YConstraint of an image present inside a relative layout in Xamarin fomrs

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a requirement in Xamarin forms where an image positioned in RelativeLayout needs to be changed based on a condition. I can get the condition only through the code. Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Test.Views.Home">  <ContentPage.Content>
<RelativeLayout>      
  <ContentView
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1}">
  </ContentView>
  <Image Source="imageButton.png"
                     x:Name="FloatButton"
                     HeightRequest="100"
                     WidthRequest="100"
                     RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1, Constant=-98}"
                     RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1, Constant=-113}"/>
</RelativeLayout>  </ContentPage.Content></ContentPage>
```

Here if you see the RelativeLayout.YConstraint of Image control, i need to change the expression to

RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1, Constant=-250}"/>

How can i do it through code? Note that i need to set it like the above xaml code initially and on some conditions which i get inside the code, i need to change the YConstraint like the above code. Can anyone pls help me?

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22675/set-relativelayout-constraint-expression-from-code

Comment: If the link of forum is not clear enough or doesn't work for you let me know I will provide an answer

Comment: I do not want any animations and all. I just need to change the position of an existing image to  RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1, Constant=-250}"/>. Also i tried the above discussion details, but did not help me though

Comment: to disable animation you can specify in LayoutTo duration 0. There is no other way to change constraints programmatically

Comment: there is another suggestion "You can update the constraints from code via view's setBoundsConstrains method followed by calling view's forceLayout method" I have not tried that

Comment: I tried this and it did not workout  var b = FloatButton.Bounds;
                b.Y = b.Y - 50;
                await FloatButton.LayoutTo(b, 250, Easing.SinIn);
                rlMain.ForceLayout();

Comment: What doesn't mean - didn't work? It didn't move? If you use LayoutTo you don't need ForceLayout. Force required only if you setBoundsConstraints

Comment: I tried both way, but did not help. However I had a workaround by placing two images in the required positions and hiding one at a time based on the condition.