# Boxview "LinearGradientBrush"

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I do same gradient effect like in the code below in `xamarin forms`?

The same effect in `WPF`:

```
<Rectangle Width="200" Height="100">
  <Rectangle.Fill>
    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
      <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.0" />
      <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.25" />
      <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.75" />
      <GradientStop Color="LimeGreen" Offset="1.0" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

My Boxview in `xamarin forms`:

```
<BoxView WidthRequest="100" Grid.RowSpan="2">

</BoxView>
```

Comment: https://github.com/sthewissen/Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is more than one way to do it. You can use SkiaSharp to achieve the result. Otherwise, you can write custom renderers to do the same.

> Refer to the [Xamarin documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/effects/shaders/linear-gradient) here if you wish to use the `SkiaSharp` library.

Refer below links if you wish to use custom renderers to achieve the result.

- [Add Gradient background to layouts in Xamarin Forms visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848545/add-gradient-background-to-layouts-in-xamarin-forms-visual-studio)
- [Horizontal And Vertical Gradient Color In Xamarin.Forms](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/horizontal-and-vertical-gradient-color-in-xamarin-forms/)

There is an awesome custom control `MagicGradients` available for doing some excellent gradient works which would be very handy if you prefer to write very less code.

Refer to the below links:

- [GitHub source code - MagicGradients](https://github.com/mgierlasinski/MagicGradients)
- [NuGet Package - MagicGradients](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MagicGradients)

> There is also an [excellent blog](https://medium.com/@benetskyybogdan/gradient-background-for-your-xamarin-forms-app-6d7e46fba558) available for the same on how to use the control if you are a beginner.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Please accept the answer if that helps so that it can be useful for others as well. Happy coding 

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use BoxView to achieve the effect,you could use customRenderer.

1.in your PCL project:

```
public class GradientColorView :BoxView
{
    public Color StartColor { get; set; }
    public Color MidOneColor { get; set; }
    public Color MidTwoColor { get; set; }
    public Color EndColor { get; set; }
}
```

2.in Android project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(GradientColorView), typeof(GradientColorViewRenderer))]
namespace App18.Droid
{
  public class GradientColorViewRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<BoxView>
   {

    public GradientColorViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }
    private Color StartColor { get; set; }
    public Color MidOneColor { get; set; }
    public Color MidTwoColor { get; set; }
    private Color EndColor { get; set; }

    protected override void DispatchDraw(global::Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
    {
        #region for Vertical Gradient
        //var gradient = new Android.Graphics.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, Height,
        #endregion

        #region for Horizontal Gradient
        var gradient = new Android.Graphics.LinearGradient(0, 0, Width, 0,new int[] {
               this.StartColor.ToAndroid(),
               this.MidOneColor.ToAndroid(),
               this.MidTwoColor.ToAndroid(),
               this.EndColor.ToAndroid()},new float[] {0.0f,0.25f,0.75f,1.0f },
        #endregion

               Android.Graphics.Shader.TileMode.Mirror);

        var paint = new Android.Graphics.Paint()
        {
            Dither = true,
        };
        paint.SetShader(gradient);
        canvas.DrawPaint(paint);
        base.DispatchDraw(canvas);
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<BoxView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            var view = e.NewElement as GradientColorView;
            this.StartColor = view.StartColor;
            this.MidOneColor = view.MidOneColor;
            this.MidTwoColor = view.MidTwoColor;
            this.EndColor = view.EndColor;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
 }
}
```

3.in ios project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(GradientColorView), typeof(GradientColorViewRenderer))]
namespace App18.iOS
{
  public class GradientColorViewRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<BoxView>
  {
    public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
    {
        base.Draw(rect);
        GradientColorView stack = (GradientColorView)this.Element;
        CGColor startColor = stack.StartColor.ToCGColor();
        CGColor midOneColor = stack.MidOneColor.ToCGColor();
        CGColor midTwoColor = stack.MidTwoColor.ToCGColor();
        CGColor endColor = stack.EndColor.ToCGColor();

        #region for Vertical Gradient

        var gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer();

        #endregion

        #region for Horizontal Gradient

        //var gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer()
        //{
        //  StartPoint = new CGPoint(0, 0.5),
        //  EndPoint = new CGPoint(1, 0.5)
        //};

        #endregion



        gradientLayer.Frame = rect;
        gradientLayer.Colors = new CGColor[] { startColor,midOneColor,midTwoColor,endColor
    };

        NativeView.Layer.InsertSublayer(gradientLayer, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

4.in your page xaml :

```
 <local:GradientColorView HeightRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" StartColor="Yellow" MidOneColor="Red" MidTwoColor="Blue"  EndColor="LimeGreen"></local:GradientColorView>
```

Comment: it doesn't stay contained within the BoxView, it fills the whole page. Like if I make the BoxView fill ONLY 3 rows out of a 10 row Grid, it takes up the whole Grid, why is that  please Leo?