# How to access a custom StackLayout from CodeBehind in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I implemented a custom StackLayout in my Xamarin.Forms project to make the background of a ContentPage a Gradient, and I want to change the gradient flow in the code behind depending on the OS of the device. The problem is that when I assign a value to x:Name I can't find it in the xaml.cs class, therefore I cant access to its properties. Here goes the code:

Custom StackLayout code:

```
namespace MyProject.Renderers
{
    public class GradientLayout : StackLayout
    {
        public string ColorsList { get; set; }
        public Color[] Colors
        {
            get
            {
                string[] hex = ColorsList.Split(',');
                Color[] colors = new Color[hex.Length];

                for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i++)
                {
                    colors[i] = Color.FromHex(hex[i].Trim());
                }

                return colors;
            }
        }

        public GradientColorStackMode Mode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

xaml code:

```
<renderers:GradientLayout
        x:Name="theGradient"
        ColorsList="#D81BDE,#4847FF"
        Mode="ToBottomLeft">

        //Irrelevant content

</renderers:GradientLayout>
```

xaml.cs code:

```
public partial class LogInPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LogInPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
            {
                //theGradient do not appear 
            }
        }
    }
```

And that is it, if you need any more information I will provide it as soon as I see your request, thank you all for your time, have a good day.

Comment: this should work.  For weird XAML issues, try killing VS, deleting all bin/obj folders, restarting VS, and rebuilding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create custom renderer for IOS and Android like this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49862125/10627299

If so, make sure you add the `WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200"` for your `GradientLayout`

```
  <renderers:GradientLayout
   ColorsList="#dd8f68,#a9a9a9,#3a3939"
   Mode="ToBottomRight" 
   WidthRequest="200" 
   HeightRequest="200">

 </renderers:GradientLayout>
```

Here is running screenshot.

[image]

If above code is still not worked. You can use `Magic Gradients` in your applcation https://github.com/mgierlasinski/MagicGradients

Comment: I added widthRequest and HeightRequest and as you said now it is working, thank you so much. If it is not too much to ask and if you have spare time could you please explain to me what difference does giving values to these properties make. Have a nice day.